# Script doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I use a script to select a menu item and navigate to the selected location on the page:

```
$(function () {
    var topMenu = $('.nav'),
        menuItems = topMenu.find('a'),

        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
            var item = $($(this).attr('href'));
            if (item.length) {
                return item;
            }
        }),

        hash = window.location.hash;

    menuItems.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - 20;
        window.history.replaceState('', '', href);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

It works perfectly in Chrome, FF and Opera, but doesn't work absolutely in IE9,8,7.

**How to make it work in IE?**

It's my code http://jsfiddle.net/UB9f9/10/

Answer (score 1):

comment below line. **window.history.replaceState** will not work for IE 7,8,9 check compatibility chart. http://caniuse.com/#search=replaceState

//    window.history.replaceState('', '', href);

Comment: but it will not show adress with #something in the browser's navigation bar :(